# How to get in Laravel 5+ the users private storage file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hi there I am using Laravel 5.6 and Image Intervention Package.
I am making a photo website in laravel. 
The user can upload a picture, the picture is then stored in storage/app/original-photos/account/.$user_id./$filename as a original picture. Then Image intervention makes a thumbnail of that same picture and stores it in 
public/storage/original-photos/account/thumbs/.$user_id./$filename

I created a symlink. All of it is working.
But say a user wanted to see his original picture but it must NOT be accessible by typing or copying the link to the photo in the browser.

I found a way to see the photo but when I log out I can still access the picture by the link.

This is the function I made.

```
 public function original($id){
    $photo = Photo::findOrFail($id);
    $user = Auth::user()->id;
    $filename = ('app/original-photos/account/'.$user.'/'.$photo->photo);
    return response()->download(storage_path($filename), null, [], null);

}
```

So I can see the original picture but I don't wan't to be accessible with link. But the user can see the picture just don't know how.

Some help is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Deny READ permission for the guest users(you have more than one options there) directory and files on your Hosting Server.

Comment: By default, web server has access only to a public directory.

If you set public directory as root for a virtual host, no one will be able to access app or storage directories which are outside public!

Comment: Aright guys gonna try that. THnx alot. I will return when I have it tested